# I have some issue about using useRouter | Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

This is my first time using useRouter and i really dont know how it works.
I want to take props.indexUrl and added dynamiacally into the url below, i have done several ways but always getting error.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Component = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    const {
        query: { indexUrl },
    } = router;

    const props = {
        indexUrl,
    };

    return props.indexUrl;
};

export const urls = [
    {
        url:
            "click.myyellowlocal.com/k.php?ai=19202&url=http%3a%2f%2f" +
            Component,
    },
    {
        url: "cse.google.vu/url?q=https%3A%2F%2",
    },
    {
        url: "sazhs.co.kr/member/login.html?noMemberOrder=&returnUrl=http%3a%2f%2",
    },
];
```

I have try like this before

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const router = useRouter();

const {
    query: { indexUrl },
} = router;

const props = {
    indexUrl,
};

export const urls = [
    {
        url:
            "click.myyellowlocal.com/k.php?ai=19202&url=http%3a%2f%2f" +
            props.indexUrl,
    },
    {
        url: "cse.google.vu/url?q=https%3A%2F%2",
    },
    {
        url: "sazhs.co.kr/member/login.html?noMemberOrder=&returnUrl=http%3a%2f%2",
    },
];
```

and give an error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`

so i make like this

```js
const Component = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    const {
        query: { indexUrl },
    } = router;

    const props = {
        indexUrl,
    };
};
```

but i dont know how to get props.indexUrl to url like in the top code.

more detail, the router indexUrl is from other file

```js
    function sendProps() {
        Router.push({
            // pathname: "/processUrl",
            pathname: "/urlList",
            query: { indexUrl },
        });
    }
```

how to get the value of props.indexUrl and add it into the list of url dynamiacally ??

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `router.query.indexUrl`? What is the issue?

Comment: do you mean return ```router.query.indexUrl```??  i try it and give an error, like not define in the urls

Comment: No, I mean the answer to "how to get the value of props.indexUrl", isn't that just `router.query.indexUrl`, or I guess `props.indexUrl` after it is constructed? I don't understand the other part of the question, "add it into the list of url dynamically". Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete/cohesive [mcve] so it's clearer what you are trying to do with the code overall? For example, `Component` isn't a valid React component, it isn't returning JSX.

Comment: `useRouter` is a React hook so it can only be called in a React function component or a custom React hook. If I'm not mistaken this means it runs on the client side when the component mounts and is rendered (*maybe I'm wrong, I'm not super familiar with Next.js*). How are these `urls` relevant? Where are the `urls` being accessed where you want to append a queryString parameter?